# exclude directory with tar command

Tags: linux, tar, exclude

T would like to use the tar command in Linux to back up some files, but  i would like to exclude a specific directory from the archive.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, lets back up the directory /directory and everything in it, but ignoring any files called IGNORE-ME.

`tar -cf backup.tar /directory --exclude "IGNORE-ME"`

If it wasn't snowing out, i'd probably point out that `man tar` is as good as RTFM (and google 'tar exclude file' is even faster).

Answer (score 2):

You can also put all of the patterns in a file and use:

```
-X, --exclude-from=FILE
              exclude files matching patterns listed in FILE
```

Comment: much better answer than mine  -well, far more practical assuming you want to mask more than the one file :)
see, I read the man page, but obviously not all the way down to -X ;)